# Configuration for using Miracast

Tags: wireless-networking, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I need to use the Miracast feature on my PC to use the PC screen as an extension of my Notebook screen

PC informations:

```
OS               : Windows 10 Pro 22H2 build 19045.2486
Motherboard      : P8H61-M LX3 R2.0
Chipset          : H61 
Video card       : ATI Radeon HD 4600 series WDDM 1.1
Processor        : Intel i5 3330
Intel Hd Graphics: 2500                      WDDM 1.3
Monitor          : Dell U2312HM
DirectX Version  : DirectX 12
```

According to Intel's website, the H61 chipset, the HD Graphics 2500 and the ATI Radeon HD 4600 Video Card are compatible with Miracast.
I couldn't get information if the Dell U2312HM Monitor is compatible with Miracast!

When I run "dxdiag" command on PC, Miracast option appears as "Not Avaliable".

Commands executed at the prompt:

`netsh wlan show wirelesscapabilities`:

```
Interface name: Wi-Fi

    Device Wi-Fi Direct     : supported
    Wi-Fi Direct GO         : supported
    Client Wi-Fi Direct     : supported
    Coletor Miracast        : supported
```

Notice that the `Coletor Miracast` option says `Supported`.

`netsh interface show interface`:

```
Adm. State     State          Type             Interface name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled      Connected      Dedicated         VirtualBox Host-Only Network
Enabled      Connected      Dedicated         Ethernet
Enabled      Disconnected   Dedicated         Wi-Fi
Enabled      Connected      Dedicated         Local Connection* 12 - Microsoft Wi-fi Direct Virtual Adapter
```

`netsh wlan show driver`:

```
Interface name: WiFi

     Driver : TP-Link Wireless N PCI Express Adapter
     Supplier : TP-Link Technologies Co., Ltd.
     Provider : TP-Link Technologies Co., Ltd.
     Date: 05/18/2017
     Version: 2023.55.415.2017
     INF file: oem65.inf
     Type : Native Wi-Fi Driver
     Supported radio types: 802.11n 802.11g 802.11b
     Support for FIPS 140-2 mode: Yes
     Support for 802.11w Management Frame Protection: Yes
     Supported hosted network: No
     Authentication and encryption supported in infrastructure mode:
                                 Open None
                                 WPA2-Personal CCMP
                                 Open WEP-40bit
                                 Open WEP-104bit
                                 Open WEP
                                 WPA-Enterprise TKIP
                                 WPA-Personal TKIP
                                 WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                                 WPA2-Personal TKIP
                                 WPA-Enterprise CCMP
                                 WPA-Personal CCMP
                                 WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                                 Defined by vendorTKIP
                                 Defined by vendorCCMP
                                 Defined by vendor Defined by vendor
                                 Defined by vendor Defined by vendor
                                 WPA2-Enterprise Vendor Defined
                                 WPA2-Enterprise Vendor Defined
                                 Defined by vendor Defined by vendor
                                 Defined by vendor Defined by vendor
     IHV service present : Yes
     IHV adapter OUI: [00 e0 4c], type: [00]
     IHV Extensibility DLL Path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\Rtlihvs.dll
     IHV UI Extensibility ClSID: {6c2a8cca-b2a2-4d81-a3b2-4e15f445c312}
     IHV diagnostics CLSID : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
     Wireless Video Supported: No (Graphics Driver: No, Wi-Fi Driver: Yes)
```

Note:
My PC has a cable connection coming from the wifi router and also has a wifi network card installed, that is, I can access the internet both via
cable or via a wifi network card.

Why in dxdiag command Miracast is showing as `Not Avaliable`, Dell U2312HM Monitor could be the issue causing Miracast to stay `Not Avaliable`?

Comment: @Ramhound to be honest, I'm very confused with the information I checked from my PC, with the information related to Miracast support?.... honestly I don't know why Miracast in dxdiag shows up as Not Evaluable?.. Is dxgiag reporting correctly?... or do I have to update some driver? I don't know?... I ran the commands at the prompt, but they left me even more confused, after all, does my PC support Miracast or not?... I need help with that!

Comment: @Ramhound Ok thank's, can you post your answer so I can select it?